# Horror movie where two girls swim in a filthy body of water

Tags: story-identification

I only saw the beginning of this on TV, and it was a while ago- about mid 90's. What I remember is two teenage girls, possibly on the edge of graduation, both share ambitions of leaving the small town they live in. Both go to a body of water of some sort (kind of like either an aqueduct no longer used or the flooded basement of an abandoned building) because someone who moves away without swimming in this body of water "will never wash the stink of this town off of you."

I *think* there was some creature living in the body of water and the teenagers unintentionally wake it up, but I don't recall what happens after that.

Comment: I'm guessing they die.

Comment: @JackBNimble - I'm guessing that both of them have model good looks and a PhD in screaming while running.

Comment: Any chance it is [Frog Dreaming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frog_Dreaming) / The Quest (1986) ? This has a boy and two girls who discover a monster in a flooded quarry / filthy lake. They are swimming in the lake and the monster attacks them.

Comment: @JackBNimble- the wikipedia entry on Frog Dreaming says it takes place in Australia- I'm fairly certain this movie is set somewhere in the States.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The title of this 1991 vampire movie is [*Children of the Night*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0103957/?ref_=tt_urv), and it starred Karen Black.  I have a copy on DVD.  The full movie is on [youtube](https://youtu.be/uDRa9RwEkCY?t=8m41s).  That link should take you directly to the scene where the two girls discuss the tradition that a kid who is leaving town must swim in the flooded crypt of the abandoned church to "wash the dirt of the town off you, otherwise you'll be back".

While swimming, one of the girls loses a cross necklace.  It falls onto the head of an ancient vampire that is sleeping at the bottom of the crypt, and this revives the beast.  All hell breaks loose as the vampire ravages the town in search of the virginal girl who awoke him.

The most memorable shot in the movie is that of the submerged vampire.  Its long hair drifts in the corrupt water like vile tendrils, and its lungs and esophagus are turned inside out and floating out of its mouth, the lungs puffing away like the gills of a fish.

Answer (score 3):

"Creepshow 2" (1987)?

It sounds like the 2nd tale in this anthology movie containing 3 stories. It was called The Raft, and was based on a short story by Stephen King.

Here is the full movie from YouTube:

Comment: FYI , the swimming scene starts at ~38 minutes..

Comment: I thought the same! But it's a group of boys and girls in *The Raft*, and it's not about leaving town. And except for the "creature", the lake is not filthy. So I don't think this is it.

Comment: @theguest I'm not the person who asked the question :P Just commenting that at first I thought the same as you, then realized this can't be the answer :)

Comment: Interesting movie, but no, that's not it.